# Components getting deleted

Tags: aem

I have created a project in AEM using maven archetype command and when I am creating a new components and saving it by running, mvn clean install          -PautoInstallPackage command the components are getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export them via content package add them to your project. I guess you override them because of your filter settings.